# Can Azure Insights API be used for completely stand-alone custom metrics?

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights, azure-diagnostics

I am hoping I can put in some simple API calls in legacy systems so I can capture point-in-time metrics "somewhere" in Azure, so that I can then take advantage of the Azure Portal dashboard and metrics graphing. I looked into Insights SDK but that seems to require that whatever I'm running be deployed somewhere in Azure cloud. I just want to run a simple powershell script or simple .net console app that connects to a legacy database in our internal network, pulls very basic point-in-time counts for message processing backlog... and then pushes that info with a timestamp out "somewhere" for visualization.

Any ideas what I can use for this in Azure?

Thanks,
Andres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TrackMetric API in Application Insights SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics